# WxPython offline installation on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: software-installation

How can I install WxPython offline on my Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: You should not ask the same a question twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the WxPython package for your architecture at the Ubuntu Packages website, here is the [link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/python-wxgtk2.8).

But you should know that that the recommended way would be installing it through the Ubuntu Software Center, with `sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8` or with Synaptic Package Manager for example, doing so will allow you to have the latest version of the software by a simple update when a new version is released.

**Note:** In my case wxPython is already installed, so maybe this package is installed by default on your Ubuntu too.